Altnerative prove to there is a unique $A\in\mathscr{P}(U)$ such that for every $B\in\mathscr{P}(U), A\cup B = B$
Prove that there is a unique $A\in\mathscr{P}(U)$ such that for every $B\in\mathscr{P}(U), A\cup B = B$
I have no trouble proofing its existence.
To proof it's Uniqueness.
(Letting y and z be an arbitrary of $A\in \mathscr{P}(U)$)
Suppose $ \forall B\in \mathscr{P}(U)(y \cup B =B) $ and  $ \forall B\in \mathscr{P}(U)(z\cup B =B) $. Since B can be anything, suppose $B=\emptyset$, it follows that $y \cup \emptyset = \emptyset$ and $z \cup \emptyset = \emptyset$. Hence $y=z$.
Is my proof for uniqueness valid? I tried to convert the question into this general statement: Letting $P(A)$ be $\forall B \in \mathscr{P}(U)(A\cup B)$  and  $\forall y \forall z (P(z) \land P(z) \to y=z) $ to proof its uniqueness.

What are $y,z$?  Seems simple to argue that $A$ must be empty.  After all, taking $B=\emptyset$ gives $A\cup \emptyset=\emptyset\implies A=\emptyset$.

General recommendation: write proofs like these using English sentences with minimal notation. Arguments with logical symbols are hard to read and easy to get wrong.

As a variant, note that if $A_1, A_2$ are two solutions then $A_1\cup A_2=A_2$ by assumption, but $A_1\cup A_2=A_2\cup A_1=A_1$, again by assumption.

FYI - "Proof" is a noun. "Prove" is the corresponding verb. You "prove" something by giving a "proof". You used them correctly twice: the very first word of the post, and when you asked if your proof was correct (it is, by the way - the other comments are just pointing out improvements in clarity and style). In every other instance, you chose the wrong word.
